# Logging on to a website, How are Cookies involved?

Tags: .net, cookies, f#, httpwebrequest, fiddler

Ok, so i'm writting a program that need to log in to a website, want the scrape some information out of it.

He're is my code for loging on:

```
module Webscraper = 
    open System.Net
    open HtmlAgilityPack
    open Lolcr.Model
    open System.Collections.Specialized

    let logon = fun (address:string) studentNumber password->
        let upload values =
            let wc = new WebClient()
            wc.UploadValues (address, values)
        let ToNameValueCollection nvs =
            let col = new NameValueCollection()
            for nv in nvs do
                match nv with (n, v) -> col.Add(n, v);
            col
        let fields :List<string*string> = 
            ("v_studentid",studentNumber) ::
            ("v_studentpin", password) ::
            ("b3", "Login") :: []
            let resp = fields |> ToNameValueCollection |> upload;
            resp |> Array.map char |> System.String.Concat

//and for viewing a page within the site:
    let pageAt = fun (address : string) ->
        let getWebStream = 
            let req = HttpWebRequest.Create address
            let resp = req.GetResponse()
            resp.GetResponseStream

        let doc = new HtmlDocument()
        getWebStream() |> doc.Load;
        doc.DocumentNode
```

Now when I call logon, it returns the text of the logon page as if i hadden't loged on (poss cos logging on would have done a redirect in the browser)
when I call PageAt on the page Im interested in it retuyrns the "Please log in" page.

Looking at what is happening from Fiddler2: (Where XXXX and YYYY are studentNumber and password respecitively):

```
//Via firefox    
POST https://server2.olcr.uwa.edu.au/olcrstudent/index.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: server2.olcr.uwa.edu.au
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://server2.olcr.uwa.edu.au/olcrstudent/
Cookie: JSESSIONID=18F87DFEB1555A6FA644215FDAE5E506; __utma=55889711.14817822.1328281214.1328281214.1328281214.1; __utmz=55889711.1328281214.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=olcr%20uwa; __utmb=55889711.1.10.1328281214; __utmc=55889711
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 53

v_studentid=XXXX&v_studentpin=YYYY&b3=Login


//From my program:
POST https://server2.olcr.uwa.edu.au/olcrstudent/index.jsp HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: server2.olcr.uwa.edu.au
Content-Length: 53
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

v_studentid=XXXX&v_studentpin=YYYY&b3=Login
```

So the big difference from my looking at it is that i'm not sending any cookies  <s>(I'm actually not entirely sure what cookies are, come to think of it (I'll look that up</s> (EDIT:Done)))

So should I be sending cookies?
What are the mechanisms for this in .net?
Should I be doing somehtingdiffernt cos this is HTTPS?

Comment: "So the big difference from my looking at it is that i'm not sending any cookies (I'm actually not entirely sure what cookies are, come to think of it (I'll look that up)) " Do this first. then come back ask a question IF NEEDED.

Comment: It's spelled "logging" on ...

Comment: I have now looked up what cookies are precisely (I had a Vague understanding before), and believe my question is still correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, normally you will need to persist cookies to log in to sites.
A CookieAwareWebclient such as the one from: [this blog](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com.au/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html),
makes it simple.
The F# equivelent is

```
type CookieAwareWebclient (cookies) = 
    inherit WebClient()
    member this.CookieContainer = cookies

    new () = new CookieAwareWebclient(new CookieContainer())

    override this.GetWebRequest (address:Uri) =
        let req = base.GetWebRequest address
        match req with 
        | :? HttpWebRequest as httpReq -> 
            httpReq.CookieContainer <- this.CookieContainer;
            upcast httpReq
        | _ -> req;
```

Now so long as you do all your webrequests though the *same* Webclient (so you will have to make the webclient accessable throughout the module, and change pageAt to use the it)
you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you log into a website you have to have some way for the site to track as you go from page to page.

This is usually done with either a cookie, or a session identifier in the URL.

Now, you need to know the difference between two types of cookies.

One is a session cookie, which stays in memory on the client machine then goes away after you close your browser (or the session closes). These only contain a unique identifier that references the users unique session instance on the server. This allows the server to know who you are with each subsequence page hit.

The other type of cookie is a physical cookie which you specicially set to save specific variables in a text file on the client machine.

If you look at your response, you have a reference to a session ID, which means you do have a session cookie on the client machine:

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=18F87DFEB1555A6FA644215FDAE5E506; __utma=55889711.14817822.1328281214.1328281214.1328281214.1; __utmz=55889711.1328281214.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=olcr%20uwa; __utmb=55889711.1.10.1328281214; __utmc=55889711
```

This cookie is created by default in asp.net if you ever use session.

Comment: This answer in no way tells the OP how to persist cookies so the web site can be logged in to.

Comment: After making sure that he understood what a cookie really was, I pointed out that he is already using a session cookie on his site, and that it was created automatically by .net whenever session is used.  What information would you say is missing from my answer, and worthy of a downvote?

Comment: 1) I didn't downvote. 2) .Net `WebRequest`s have no cookie container by default. The _server_ may try to give you a session cookie, but the client needs to persist it, and that's what the OP needs to know how to do.

Comment: Indeed, I'm writing the client, not the server. I worked it now now, thanks for your input none the less.